# Using Loops to convert int to string then back to int

Tags: java, android, string, loops, int

This is the code

```
@Override
  public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) {
      getAccelerometer(event);
    }

  }

  private void getAccelerometer(SensorEvent event) {
    float[] values = event.values;
    //Movement
    float x = values[0];
    float y = values[1];
    float z = values[2];

    float accelationSquareRoot = (x * x + y * y + z * z)
        / (SensorManager.GRAVITY_EARTH * SensorManager.GRAVITY_EARTH);
    long actualTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    if (accelationSquareRoot >= 2) //
    {
      if (actualTime - lastUpdate < 200) {
        return;
      }


      if (distance <= 50 && distance > 40) {
        view.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
        while (distance > 0) {
              distance--;
              Integer.toString(distance);
              lastUpdate = actualTime;
              Toast.makeText(this, distance, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                  .show();
              int distance = Integer.parseInt(distance);


        }

        if (distance < 40){
            view.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
        }



      } else {
          view.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);

      } 
      color = !color;
    }
  }
```

I am trying to use the distance variable to be reduced and viewed in a toast every time I shake the device.

This is where the code goes wrong.

```
  int distance = Integer.parseInt(distance);
```

It wants me to change the name of my variable. If I do that my loop won't work.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Although it's not in your code snippet, the variable `distance` is already declared somewhere before the problematic line, and you can't reuse the same name for a newly declared variable in the same scope. Either remove the preceding `int` declaration or use another variable name.

Answer (score 5):

Why don't you leave the distance as an int value and use a `String.format()` in your `Toast` instead? i.e.

```
Toast.makeText(this, String.format("%d", distance), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

From a UI point of view I'm not sure I'd like to be spamming Toast messages on every iteration of a loop though, perhaps updating a `TextView` widget might be better.

Answer (score 0):

The error is because you declare twice the same variable. Also, you don't need to convert `distance` to `String` to show it in the `Toast`, just add `"" +` before `distance`. So by doing this, you can remove both these lines :

```
Integer.toString(distance); 
int distance = Integer.parseInt(distance);
```

Answer (score 0):

So you're converting distance from an int to a string and then back again? Could you use another variable for your string, to save this type conversion headache?

Edit: Beaten by Karl and jbihan. Their answers compliment each other. You can lose two lines AND fix your problem.